# How to call a Javascript function from Python

Tags: javascript, python, client-server

I have a python code (server side) which doesn't interact with client side. However, I need to represent some items when it (server code) will has done. The only idea I came up with is the JS function which represents an item, calling from Python. Could you advise me either packages or another idea to implement this.

**Some Details** (I do not aware is it necessary, but might be it's helpful)

```py
async def start_delete_delay(app, delay):
    """
    The very function which thrust a delay for each front token.
    Key arguments:
    app -- our application.
    delay -- a delay in seconds
    """
    async with app['db'].acquire() as conn:

        # First of all we need to check for database emptiness
        query = text("SELECT True FROM tokens LIMIT(1)")
        if await conn.fetch(query):

            # If database is not empty then we are processing a waiting delay.
            # First, fetching an id & related token from the first position (due to it queue) from database.
            query = select([db.tokens.c.id, db.tokens.c.token]).order_by(asc(db.tokens.c.id)).limit(1)
            query_result = await conn.fetchrow(query)

            # Retrieving an id and token
            id_before_sleep, token = query_result['id'], query_result['token']

            # Setting a delay
            try:
                await asyncio.sleep(delay)

            # Some information related with cancellation error
            # https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                pass

            # Check whether a token at the first place as same as it was before
            finally:

                # If it possible but all of members picked their tokens over 60 seconds.
                if await conn.fetch(text("SELECT True FROM tokens LIMIT(1)")):
                    query_result = await conn.fetchrow(query)
                    id_after_sleep = query_result['id']

                    # If they are same then we delete that token and starting delay again.
                    if id_before_sleep == id_after_sleep:
                        query = delete(db.tokens).where(db.tokens.c.id == id_before_sleep)

                        # preparing a token for reuse.
                        app['new_token'].prepare_used_token(token)

                        # Deleting a token
                        await conn.fetchrow(query)

                        # I'd like to call a JS function (which I already have) here

                        # Starting a delay for adjacent token, over and over and over
                        task = make_task(start_delete_delay, app, delay)
                        asyncio.gather(task)
```

Comment: What's the workflow? The user hits a web page and it fires off a request to python to start processing and then when python is done the results show up?

Comment: @mkaatman not in this case. It’s a queue management system. I have queue representation on the web page. The function above has to delete a token after a delay, and I want to represent new queue on the web page.

Comment: How should the web page know that their is a new queue? Will it poll and check some data source for queue information?

Comment: Yes. Each 60 seconds occurs token deleting from a queue (as same as from database), hence the queue updating. And at this point I want to call JS function which updates web-page with updated queue.

Comment: It may be helpful to think of it from the other direction. The JS is running in the browser making a web service call every X seconds. If that's the direction you want to go, then you need to figure out what language you want to implement the web service in and what data source you'll use for queue information.

Comment: I will try, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions, so if someone faced with such problems try to use them:

**First solution**

The clue is WebSockets. I used `aiohttp` and `asyncio`.

In JavaScript file I added up a listening socket:

```js
var socket = new WebSocket('/link-to-websocket')
```

In server-side I added a websocket_handler, in my case it sending the message after deleting a toke from database

```py
async def websocket_handler(request):

    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)

    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
            if app['updt_flag']:
                await ws.send_str("signal")
            else:
                await ws.close()
    return ws
```

And adding it to routes

```py
app.add_routes([web.get('/link-to-websocket', websocket_handler)])
```

1) [How JavaScript works: Deep dive into WebSockets and HTTP/2 with SSE + how to pick the right path](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-deep-dive-into-websockets-and-http-2-with-sse-how-to-pick-the-right-path-584e6b8e3bf7)

2) [Python aiohttp websockets](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#websockets)

However this method isn't the best, we don't use entire websocket's functionality therefore let's go ahead to another method: Server-Sent Events (SSE). This method is more suitable for the my problem because we always receiving response from server without request to it (whereas websockets doesn't incorporate such option):

**Second solution**
As I said above I will use SSE and for these purposes it required a sse-package

`pip install aiohttp_sse`

```py
import asyncio
from aiohttp_sse import sse_response


async def SSE_request(request):
    loop = request.app.loop
    async with sse_response(request) as resp:
        while True:
            if request.app['updt_flag']:
                await resp.send("signal")
                request.app['updt_flag'] = False
            await asyncio.sleep(1, loop=loop)
    return resp
```

Adding route

`web.get('/update', SSE_request)`

Adding listening sse to JS:

```js
const evtSource = new EventSource("/update");
evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
                    display_queue_remove();
}
```

Thats all:)